# Construct DataFrame from multiple JSON files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to convert multiple json files into a dataframe. I only want some entries that match some criteria from those files, but I'm appending the whole converted files, then filtering it.

Suppose I have 2 json files that look like this:

File 1500.json

```
[
  {
    "CodStore": 1500,
    "CodItem": 10,
    "NameItem": "Burger",
    "Price": 10.0
  },
  {
    "CodStore": 1500,
    "CodItem": 20,
    "NameItem": "Fries",
    "Price": 3.0
  },
  {
    "CodStore": 1500,
    "CodItem": 30,
    "NameItem": "Ice Cream",
    "Price": 1.0
  }
]
```

File 1805.json

```
[
  {
    "CodStore": 1805,
    "CodItem": 10,
    "NameItem": "Burger",
    "Price": 9.0
  },
  {
    "CodStore": 1805,
    "CodItem": 20,
    "NameItem": "Fries",
    "Price": 2.0
  },
  {
    "CodStore": 1805,
    "CodItem": 30,
    "NameItem": "Ice Cream",
    "Price": 0.5
  }
]
```

I only want entries with CodItem 10 and 30 on my dataframe, so my python code looks like this:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, read_json

df = DataFrame()

stores = [1500, 1805]

for store in stores:
    filename = '%s.json' % store
    df = df.append(read_json(filename))

df = df[(df.CodItem == 10) | (df.CodItem == 30)]
```

This is just an example, the problem is that I have more than 600+ json files so reading takes a lot of time, the dataframe becomes very long and memory consumption is very high.

Is there a way to read only the matching criteria to the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to append your JSON data to a list, then convert once at the end and filter.

```
coditems = [10, 30]

data = []
for filename in json_files:
    data.extend(read_json(filename))

df = pd.DataFrame(data).query('CodItem in @coditems')
```

This should be a lot faster because `append` is a quadratic operation. You have to read all the data in *anyway*, so you may as well use pandas to speed it up.

---

Another option would be to initialise your DataFrames inside a loop and then call `pd.concat` after you're done.

```
df_list = []
for file in json_files:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records(read_json(filename)))

df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True).query('CodItem in @coditems')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can create a temporary data frame within your loop and filter it before appending:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, read_json

df = DataFrame()

stores = [1500, 1805]

for store in stores:
    filename = '%s.json' % store
    temp_df = read_json(filename)
    df = df.append(temp_df[(temp_df.CodItem == 10) | (temp_df.CodItem == 30)])
```